# Symfony Deploying Project on Distant Server ContextErrorException

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to upload my project on the distant server, I simply uploaded the files on the distant server, checked the config.php, which says that all is good. I have removed the if conditions for only local access. But when i try to open the app_dev.php or app.php i keep getting this error

```
  ContextErrorException: Warning: 
        file_get_contents(C:\wamp2\www\Symfony\src\Les\CouvertsBundle/Resources/views/Couverts/index.html.twig)
        : failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
        in /homepages/26/d367595533/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php line 130
```

i have not found any answers to this question, maybe not looking for it properly. But could anyone explain to me why would this error is occuring? Why is symfony looking for the files with the local address?

I followed this tutorial to deploy project in production http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/deployer-son-site-symfony2-en-production. The steps seem pretty straight forward, but maybe i am missing something.

This is really frustrating, because my project is ready but i can't seem to put it online due to this problem.

Comment: My first guess is that you've uploaded the production cache from your local machine. If you delete that, you code may well work.

Comment: please post the src\Les\CouvertsBundle/Resources/views/Couverts/index.html.twig file

Comment: @Nextar The problem is evidently not with the content of the file (a) because it works locally and (b) because the error shows that PHP is looking for a Windows directory structure on a Linux machine.

Comment: may you put a hardcoded file path there, so I asked

Comment: @lonesomeday In theory, if i copy paste the source code on the server and config.php validates the configuration, the project should work right?

Comment: @lonesomeday i reuploaded the project after having cleared both the cache for dev and prod. I still get the same Error. !  I donno what to do. Totally Stuck

Answer (score 4):

The problem seemed to be the command `php app/console cache:clear` and `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` didn't completely clear the cache folder.

It can happen if the user running the command hasn't the permission to delete files/folder in app/cache/ Manually removing the content of this folder can solve the issue (`rm -rf app/cache/*`).

Answer (score 0):

Just clearing the cache manually at (projectname/app/cache) instead of the command line worked for me (version 2.8).